# Is madwifi-ng driver better for cracking?

Tags: linux, aircrack-ng

I'm very new in cracking and wireless network, and I just follow tutorials of airckrack.
Unfortunately, network card change it's channel to -1 every time I try to inject.

This is output of "airmon-ng start":

```
$ airmon-ng start wlan0 3

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Atheros     ath5k - [phy0]
                    (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

And this is of aireplay-ng:

```
$ sudo aireplay-ng -9 -e essid -a 11:22:33:44:55:66 mon0
16:18:19  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 11:22:33:44:55:66) on channel -1
16:18:19  mon0 is on channel -1, but the AP uses channel 3
```

But my question is much more general - what is better for all cracking process: installing of madwifi-ng driver or continue using native driver?

Comment: Questions asking *what is better* is highly subjective and thus not a good fit for SuperUser. [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using this for internal penetration/security testing, and not doing illegal things like breaking into others' networks.

In terms of 'better', it usually just boils down to whether a particular driver can do injection or not. If the native driver can inject with your card, then it's sufficient. If it can't, then try the `madwifi-ng` driver. If that driver can't either, then it doesn't really matter which you use, assuming both can monitor all frames being sent wirelessly. If the native driver won't even let you put the card into promiscuous mode, then try the madwifi-ng.

In any case, if you can't use injection, then you will not be able to fully test your network and you should purchase an Atheros or other model USB card which is fully supported by its drivers.